# MySql - How to query multiple boolean columns?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have 15 boolean columns in my SQL table.
I want to query in an efficient way withot using :

```
"bool1 = bool1Val AND bool2=bool2Val AND bool3=bool3Val....."
```

is there any way to do it better?

Thanks a lot

Comment: what  is type of your column?

Comment: By efficient you mean the query being easier to type? Otherwise I don't see anything inefficient about it.

Comment: what do you mean? it's boolean - true or false. Now I notices that in DB it is saved as 0 or 1

Comment: yes- I was wondering if I can avoid writting 15 times AND x=x1..

Comment: Well, you can pack them into a SET column and use `WHERE new_col = 'bool2,bool3,bool5'`.

Comment: You could write a procedure(function) which has 15 bool parameters - that would reduce the number of characters you have to type, but it could (!!) also decrease the performance a bit

Answer (score 1):

You can combine these columns into a single string column of 0's and 1's and read them at single query like 0011 means false false true true.

Have a char 16 to store this. (just a database optimisation)

```
    // courtesy @amitmahajan comment
    String selectTableSQL = "SELECT USER_FLAGS from DBUSER"; 
    Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement(); 
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(selectTableSQL); 
    while (rs.next()) 
    { 
    String userFlags = rs.getString("USER_FLAGS”); 
    boolean isUserEnabled = userFlags.charAt(0)==1?true:false; 
    }
```

Comment: it would be great if you put here some sample code which is more helpful :)

Comment: String selectTableSQL = "SELECT USER_FLAGS from DBUSER";
Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(selectTableSQL);
while (rs.next()) {
 String userFlags = rs.getString("USER_FLAGS”);
 boolean isUserEnabled = userFlags.charAt(0)==1?true:false;
}

Comment: Thanks tinka, how did you make the code appear like that

Comment: just put the code and select code and press ctrl + K http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer